# Help understanding this line in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun dump-db ()
  (dolist (cd *db*)
    (format t "~{~a:~10t~a~%~}~%" cd)))
```

The `dolist` makes it go through every element of the list `*db*` with the variable `cd` right?

and `~a` means print it in a more readable form, but these two confuse me.

`~{ ~}` does this mean anything in between will be the way every element of `*db*` will be formatted?

What's the `:` in `~{~a:`?

Comment: You should use the code formatting tool, which looks like `{}`.

Comment: I already fixed the formatting, then the OP rolled back the changes, then someone tried to edit and now the thing is locked until the edit is rejected or approved. Stupid SO editing system...

Answer (score 10):

> [The] iteration directive `~{` [...] tells `FORMAT` to iterate over the elements of a list or over the implicit list of the format arguments. [1](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html#iteration)

The `:` isn't a `format` directive, it's just printed verbatim in after each element:

```
> (format t "~{~a: ~}" '(foo bar))
FOO: BAR:
```

Comment: @neil: if this helps you enough, then please consider accepting the answer.